# Incremental OTA package android power down issue

Tags: android, ota

I created a OTA incremental package for imx6 board using the release tools provide by AOSP.  I deployed the package in the imx6 board and it updates successfully.

Now the problem is while updating the package, if power failure arises, then the patch is half upgraded and its not in the safe state.
But if i deploy full OTA package, if power failure arises, it reboots into recovery all the time until the package is fully upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I found there is a problem with u-boot source.  Once i fixed it got solved.

Thanks,